# Android - How to show AlertDialog before finishing activity?

Tags: android

I'm trying to implement this code

```
    if(someCondition){
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage("message")
        .setPositiveButton("Yes", this)
        .setNegativeButton("No", this);
        builder.show();
    }
    finish();
```

The problem is that the activity calls finish() before dialog is shown up so it throws the following exception

```
MyActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@40704090 that was originally added here
```

How to handle that?

Comment: Why are you calling finish?  What's the purpose of this Activity?

Comment: It's complicated to explain the whole purpose of this Activity, but calling finish() is mandatory and I must handle the AlertDialog before calling finish(). Anyway it's a transition Activity that's doing some process and should terminate after finishing. It's not displaying a layout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if(someCondition){
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage("message")
    .setPositiveButton("Yes", this)
    .setNegativeButton("No", this);
    builder.show();
} else {
    finish(); 
}
```

And in the Handler for the button click put the finish again.

Comment: It's working, but Sam's solution is more suitable for my case. Thanks very much :)

Comment: Sam's code doesn't solve the case where someCondition == false. I think I'll accept your answer. Thanks for your effort.

Answer (score 3):

Use an [OnDismissListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/DialogInterface.OnDismissListener.html) to call `finish()` when the dialog is closed. This way the user can respond to the Dialog and the Activity can still be closed.

---

```
if(someCondition) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage("message");
        .setPositiveButton("Yes", this)
        .setNegativeButton("No", this);

    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.setOnDismissListener(new OnDismissListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
            finish();
        }
    });
    dialog.show();
}
else {
    finish();
}
```

Comment: Do you mean I should remove finish() after the condition and write it in a dismiss listener? if so, what if someCondition == false?

Comment: I assume from your example that you want to call finish regardless of which Button is pushed, an OnDismissListener will conveniently handle both. I posted an example, you can easy add a condition there.

Comment: But that doesn't solve the case of my first comment. The dialog may not be shown at all.

Comment: Your first comment seemed to answer itself, but I explicitly added it to my example.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the following error:

```
MyActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@40704090 that was originally added here
```

because the builder has to be dismissed before the activity is finished. So I guess you will have to redesign how you would like your activity to be finished. Perhaps you would like it to finish when the "No" button is clicked?

I hope this helps.

Comment: Pressing "Yes" is doing some stuff, pressing "No" is doing some other stuff. And I need to finish() either way

Comment: Well then let the stuff be executed and once that has been done, then finish the activity.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the question really is, but the error you are getting is because you finish the activity while a dialog is showing. What i often do is call `dialog.dismiss()` in the `onPause` or `onStop` method of my activity.

What about this code?:

Some where in your activity;

```
private AlertDialog dialog;
```

the onPause or onStop method,

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if(dialog != null){
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Building the dialog,

```
    if(someCondition){
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage("message")
        .setPositiveButton("Yes", new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                //do stuff
                 //finish?
            }
        });
        .setNegativeButton("No", new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                //do stuff
                //finish?
            }
        });
        dialog = builder.show();
    }
```